# SQL update set subquery

Tags: sql, postgresql

The problem is that i failed to update a table with subquery in the set statement

Error invalid query: code: 8001 context: single-row subquery returns more than one row query: 3109398 location:

```
update tableA as A
set name = name || ',' || (select distinct B.number
from tableB as B
where B.number is not null
and B.ID like 'ID%'
order by B.number) || ',' 
where C.number = (select number from tableC
                   where C.number = 1)
```

The expected result is update the name colume of table A when the value of name = name+","+B.number. , the condition is replace the value of colume name with C.number.

Comment: Please tag the database that you are using

Comment: Please run the subquery separately in order to know which subquery returns more than one row first

Comment: Could you please show some sample input data of your tables and the expected changes which should be done by the update command?

Answer (score 0):

```
    update tableA as A
set name = name || ',' || (select distinct B.number
from tableB as B
where B.number is not null
and B.ID like 'ID%'
order by B.number) || ',' 
where C.number in (select number from tableC
                   where C.number = 1)
```

you should change
"Where C.Number = " into "Where C.Number in "